# Groupby: Getting 'Count' and 'Percentage' In Same Table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I'm working on the `tips` dataset:

```
# Load the data
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
tips.head()

total_bill  tip     sex  smoker day  time  size
0   16.99   1.01    Female  No  Sun Dinner  2
1   10.34   1.66    Male    No  Sun Dinner  3
2   21.01   3.50    Male    No  Sun Dinner  3
3   23.68   3.31    Male    No  Sun Dinner  2
4   24.59   3.61    Female  No  Sun Dinner  4
```

I want to `groupby` the `time` and `smoker` columns and then count the number of smokers in each group (including their percentage). I'm trying to achieve that in 2 steps:

**Step 1:**

```
# Count by groups
tips.groupby(['time', 'smoker']).agg({'smoker': 'count'})
               smoker
time    smoker  
Lunch    Yes    23
         No     45
Dinner   Yes    70
         No    106
```

**Step 2:**

```
# Count with percentage
tips.groupby(['time', 'smoker']).agg({'smoker': 'count'}).transform(lambda x: x/x.sum()*100)
                 smoker
time    smoker  
Lunch    Yes    9.426230
          No    18.442623
Dinner   Yes    28.688525
          No    43.442623
```

I'm getting the results in 2 separate tables. I want to get the `count` as well as `percentage` in the same table.

**Desired output:**

```
               count   percentage
time    smoker  
Lunch    Yes    23     9.426230
         No     45     18.442623
Dinner   Yes    70     28.688525
         No    106     43.442623
```

Is there any better way of doing it? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you expand your sample `df` so we can match your output? There's no "Lunch" in the "time" column for the example you provided. Else modify your output to match your example.

Comment: @not_speshal, 'Lunch' and 'Dinner' are the classes for the `time` column.

Comment: Gotcha! I re-created a dummy dataset and was able to match your required output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do multiple aggregations on the same column using [named aggregation](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation):

```
output = df.groupby(['time', 'smoker'])["smoker"].agg(Count="count", Percentage=lambda x: x.count()/df.shape[0]*100)

>>>                Count  Percentage
time   smoker                   
Dinner No        106   43.442623
       Yes        70   28.688525
Lunch  No         45   18.442623
       Yes        23    9.426230
```

###### Input df:

```
import random
df = pd.DataFrame({"time": ["Lunch"]*68+["Dinner"]*176,
                   "smoker": ["Yes"]*23+["No"]*45+["Yes"]*70+["No"]*106,
                   "sex": random.choices(["Male","Female"],k=100)})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `transform` to compute the percentage in another instruction and store the result in another column.

```
tips_grouped = tips.groupby(['time', 'smoker']).agg({'smoker': 'count'}).to_frame()
tips_grouped["percentage"] = tips_grouped["count"].transform(lambda x: x/x.sum()*100)
```